# Lookup vertically and horizontally

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to match result vertically and horizontally. How it is possible in my case? I know there is `XLOOKUP` coming but I don't have it in my version of Excel yet.

My current `VLOOKUP` attempt does not function correct as it does not take in consideration Columns, only rows.

[image]

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH?

Comment: @BigBen thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following array formula in cell AZ27, confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copy across and down:

```
=INDEX($AZ$2:$BG$24,MATCH(1,IF($AX$2:$AX$24=$AX27,IF($AY$2:$AY$24=$AY27,1)),0),MATCH(AZ$26,$AZ$1:$BG$1,0))
```

Note that array formulas are not very efficient, so you may find the calculations to be slow.  Therefore, I would suggest you use a helper column that concatenates Column AX and Column AY, and the simply use `INDEX(...,MATCH(...),MATCH(...))`.

Comment: Thank you for this! I am trying to avoid array formulas as my current calculation is quite massive already. I will try to use index match match.